# How can I use the previous return to determine if I can send the alert by Powerhsell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I'm going to use Dbatools to check my job is running or not. If it isn't running I need to send out an email alert.

I only have a few backgrounds with PowerShell programming.

```
# Import-Module D:\Tools\dbatools\dbatools.psd1 if it isn't loaded
If ( ! (Get-module dbatools )) {
Import-Module D:\Tools\dbatools\dbatools.psd1
}

# Get the job status
Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance My_SQL_Instance -Job My_Job_Name | Out-File C:\DBA\Result.txt

# Send the email alert if the job is not running
Send-MailMessage -From My_Email_Address -Subject "My_Job_Name job is not running..." -To User_Email_Address -Attachments C:\DBA\Result.txt -Body "The MiantoEDW replication job is not running..." -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer My_SmtpServer
```

I need to verify the property of  CurrentRunStatus to determine to send an email alert or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following:

```
$jobStatus = Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance My_SQL_Instance -Job My_Job_Name
$jobStatus | Select-Object Name,CurrentRunStatus | Export-Csv C:\DBA\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
if ($jobStatus.CurrentRunStatus -ne "Executing") {
    # Run some code if job is not running
    Send-MailMessage -From My_Email_Address -Subject "My_Job_Name job is not running..." -To User_Email_Address -Attachments C:\DBA\Result.csv -Body "The MiantoEDW replication job is not running..." -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer My_SmtpServer
}
else {
    # Run some code if job is running
}
```

`Get-DbaAgentJob` doesn't display the `CurrentRunStatus` property by default. You will need to retrieve it, which is done by `Select-Object CurrentRunStatus`. Since the command outputs an object, I chose to use `Export-Csv` to export a cleaner output that aligns the object properties and values. `$jobStatus` stores the output of the `Get-DbaAgentJob` command. Accessing the `$jobStatus.CurrentRunStatus` property for value `Executing` will verify if a job is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used dbatools but I assume the CurrentRunStatus is available in the Result.txt file you're outputting to?

If so, assign the result of Get-DbaAgentJob to a variable and then Out-File from that variable. Then access the CurrentRunStatus property from the variable to determine whether or not to send the alert.